# How use properly Motor in separate data access layer

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, nonblocking, tornado-motor

I started a little project using tornado and motor,
I feel some confused respect how i have to handle the access data layer if i want to have a non-bloking access

usally i separate my project with this structure

```
root_project
-logic
-data
--UsersDao
-handlers
--Users
-main.py
```

but i don't know if i do something like this the connection would be non-blocking

```
    @gen.coroutine
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self, id):
       users = self.settings["User"]
       result = yield from users.get(id)
       self.write(json_encode(result))
       self.finish()
```

'users' it's my UsersDao object and looks like

```
class UsersDao(object):
    ....
def get(self, user, callback=None):
    try:
        user = yield self._db["users"].find_one({'_id': user})
        ...create user object
        return user
    except ValueError:
        pass
    except OperationFailure:
        pass
    except Exception:
        raise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, whenever you use `yield`, you're doing something asynchronous/non-blocking. So in this case the code you've posted looks correct except for the missing `@gen.coroutine` decorator on `UsersDao.get` (whenever you use `yield` for asynchronous stuff, you need this decorator, and you need to use `yield` any time you call it).